# Any php artisan commands freeze up terminal

Tags: php, laravel, command-line-interface, laravel-5.4, laravel-artisan

I've seen a lot of people who get errors when trying to run any php artisan commands, but I am getting nothing at all - any command that I try and run stays running / frozen until I ctrl + c to quit out of it. Any tips on debugging this? I am at a loss...

Comment: `php artisan -vvv`

Comment: Yeah i tried that, it's still hanging there forever. I tried a composer dump-autoload too to no effect

Comment: In my case I had a custom logger provider, which on boot is supposed to rotate logs if it's too big, but I had just run an import before which made the log file 18Mb, which was hanging the provider and thus artisan

Answer (score 1):

Issue for me was the app could not connect to the database. Would time out after 30 seconds or maybe 300 seconds.

Solution for me was to add my ec2 server instance's new ip address to the rds database's security access group.

You may need to do something similar, or just make sure your database credentials are all correct in your app.